# params в другом контроллере

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть у меня футеры, в которые рендерится форма из `contacts_controller`,

## _runew.html.erb

```
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-0 col-xs-10 col-xs-push-1">
      <div class="footer_contacts">
        <h3>Свяжитесь с </br> нами</h3>
        <address>Адрес: проспект Павла Тичини, 1в</address>
        <address>Тел.: <a href="tel:+7777777777">+7777777777</a></address>
        <address>E-mail: <a href="mailto:info@ipass.com.ua">info@ipass.com.ua</a></address>
        <div class="social_icons">
          <a href="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
          <a href="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
          <a href="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
          <a href="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="message_form">
        <div class="input_group">
            <%= simple_form_for @contact, url: contacts_path, :method => :post  do |f|  %>
                <%= f.input :nickname, placeholder: 'Имя', :error => false, :label => false %>
                <%= f.input :mail, placeholder: 'Почта', :error => false, :label => false %>
                <%= f.input :theme, placeholder: 'Тема', :error => false, :label => false %>
        </div>
            <%= f.input :text, placeholder: 'Текст сообщения', :error => false, :label => false, as: :text %>
            <%= f.button :submit, 'Отправить' %>
            <% end %>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Вот сам контроллер для этого футера :

## contacts_controller.rb

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

    def index
    @contacts = Contact.all
    end

    def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end


  def show
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
      redirect_to :root
      ContactsMailer.sample_email(@contact).deliver_now
    end
  end


  private
  def contact_params 
    params.require(:contact).permit(:nickname, :mail, :theme, :text)
  end

end
```

У меня этот футер рендерится, например тут : view/ru/index.html.slim, и вот этот контроллер :

```
 class RuController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @contact = Contact.new
        if @contact.save
          redirect_to :root
          ContactsMailer.sample_email(@contact).deliver_now
        end
      end

      def solution
        @contact = Contact.new
        if @contact.save
          redirect_to :root
          ContactsMailer.sample_email(@contact).deliver_now
        end
      end

      def rates
        @rurates = RuRate.all
        @contact = Contact.new
        if @contact.save
          redirect_to :root
          ContactsMailer.sample_email(@contact).deliver_now
        end
      end
 
      def contact
        @contact = Contact.new
        if @contact.save
          redirect_to :root
          ContactsMailer.sample_email(@contact).deliver_now
        end
      end
    end
```

Проблема в том, что я не могу сделать приватный метод на проверку параметров в другом контроллере, и при неудачном заполнении формы оно редиректит на `/contact` с ошибкой, а надо, чтобы редиректило на `:root`, но если я так пишу, то получается бесконечный цикл...

Comment: *я не могу сделать приватный метод на проверку параметров в другом контроллере* - это уже странное желание. Для чего?